# Losing the x-axis tick titles on coreplot

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

my x axis tick mark labels seem to disappear on their own. Sometimes they show fine other times they are gone from view. I assume that it has something to do my data scaling but I've tried lots of things and I can get it fixed.  my Code follows (I pretty much copied it directly from one of 
the examples). My values are all positive.
 Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks.

```
-(void)configureHostFour {
    self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
    [self.myViewFour addSubview:self.hostView];
    CPTGraphHostingView *BarGraphView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] init];
    self.hostView.frame = CGRectMake(self.myViewFour.bounds.origin.x, self.myViewFour.bounds.origin.y, self.myViewFour.bounds.size.width, self.myViewFour.bounds.size.height);
    [self.hostView addSubview:BarGraphView];
}

-(void)configureGraphFour {
    // 1 - Create the graph
    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
    //        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme]];
    [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];

    self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    // 2 - Set graph title
    NSString *title = @"Heart Rate";
    graph.title = title;
    // 3 - Create and set text style
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 17.0f);
    // 4 - Set padding for plot area
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:1.0f];
    [graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:1.0f];
    // 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
}

-(void)configurePlotsFour {
    // 1 - Get graph and plot space
    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    // 2 - Create the plots
    CPTScatterPlot *hrPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    hrPlot.dataSource = self;
    hrPlot.identifier = hrSCORE;
    CPTColor *hrColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
    [graph addPlot:hrPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

    CPTScatterPlot *avghrPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    avghrPlot.dataSource = self;
    avghrPlot.identifier = hrSCOREAVG;
    CPTColor *avghrColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    [graph addPlot:avghrPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];


    // 3 - Set up plot space
    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:hrPlot, avghrPlot, nil]];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.1f)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.2f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

    // 4 - Create styles and symbols
    CPTMutableLineStyle *hrLineStyle = [hrPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    hrLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    hrLineStyle.lineColor = hrColor;
    hrPlot.dataLineStyle = hrLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *hrSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    hrSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = hrColor;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *avghrLineStyle = [hrPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    avghrLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;
    avghrLineStyle.lineColor = avghrColor;
    avghrPlot.dataLineStyle = avghrLineStyle;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *avghrSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    avghrSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = avghrColor;

}

-(void)configureAxesFour{
    // 1 - Create styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 10.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = .01f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];

    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 9.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    // 2 - Get axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    // 3 - Configure x-axis
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.title = @"Day of Month";
    x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    x.titleOffset = 20.0f;
    x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;

    CGFloat dateCount = [self.dateArray count];
    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dateCount];
    NSInteger i = 0;
    for (NSString *date in self.dateArray) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:date  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i++;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
        }
    }
    x.axisLabels = xLabels;
    x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;

    // 4 - Configure y-axis
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.title = @"";
    y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.titleOffset = -40.0f;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
    y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    NSInteger majorIncrement = self.hrTick;
    NSInteger minorIncrement = self.hrHalfTick;
    CGFloat yMax = 700.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
    NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
    for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
        NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
        if (mod == 0) {
            CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
            NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
            label.tickLocation = location;
            label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
            if (label) {
                [yLabels addObject:label];
            }
            [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
        } else {
            [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
        }
    }
    y.axisLabels = yLabels;
    y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
    y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;
}

#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [self.dateArray count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSInteger valueCount = [self.dateArray count];
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if (index < valueCount) {
                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            }
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:

            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:hrSCORE] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"hrscore");
                return [self.hrArray objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:hrSCOREAVG] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"hravg");
                return [self.avgHrArray objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:fgSCORE] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"gfscore");

                return [self.fgArray objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:fgSCOREAVG] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"fgavg");

                return [self.avgFgArray objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:weightSCORE] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"weight");

                return [self.weightArray objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:weightSCOREAVG] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"weight av");

                return [self.avgWeightArray objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:mapSCORE] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"map");

                return [self.mapArray objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:mapSCOREAVG] == YES) {
                NSLog(@"map avg");

                return [self.avgMapArray objectAtIndex:index];
            }

            break;
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tick locations and labels are being placed on integer values starting at zero (0). You don't say what the `xRange` is, but if its `length` is less than one (1) and it doesn't cover one of the tick locations, you won't see any ticks or labels.

Comment: Thank you. The x tick labels are showing fine, but they are just out of the frame.  They show just below the Y zero and I can scroll down to them. Is there any way to compress the Y axis. For example, if my y values are between 50 and 100 the y axis (whole graph) only shows 50 to 100. That would solve the x axis not displaying, I think. Thanks for you help.

Comment: You can use the axis constraints to lock the x-axis in position.

Comment: could you please include a code snippet for this. I cannot figure out how to do this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've got it working now. Thank you SO much for your help.

Comment: Hi, I am now plotting my x axis labels vertically, and using the following line to provide a little space under the axis  axisSet.xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:40.0];  But now the vertical length of the label bumps into the first value on the y axis. Is there a way to compress the graph a little so the first value on the y axis begins a little higher?  Thanks.